# How to set the initial value of ng-model to an empty string in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I want to be able to set my initial value for an attribute of my model as such

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selectedModel.title" name="title" value="" >
```

As shown above, I want the value of the attribute to be an empty string as to initially instantiate the input text field with an empty string.

However, currently the `ng-model="selectedModel.title"` overrides the `value=""`.

How do I get past this?

Comment: There's no reason to use the `value` attribute. In your controller, just set `$scope.selectedModel.title = "";`. Otherwise, I think you can use a `ng-init` somewhere in your HTML to do `ng-init="selectedModel.title = ''"`, but I'm not sure because I've never used `ng-init`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Set initial values in the controller

You should do this in your controller:

```
angular.module('MyModule').controller(
  'myController',
  function ($scope, MyService) {
    $scope.selectedModel = { title: '' };
  }

  // if you're using a service
  MyService.getModel().then(function (model) {
    $scope.selectedModel = model;
    // selected model doesn't have a title set, so give it a blank string as default
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.selectedModel)) {
      $scope.selectedModel.title = '';
    }
  });
);
```

You can [read more about setting the initial state of $scope in your controller here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#setting-up-the-initial-state-of-a-scope-object).

## Other Option: ng-init

The official AngularJS docs for ng-init suggest that there is only one use for ng-init, "for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat". In your case you're better off using the controller to initialize the value.

You can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit):

```
<input type="text"
       name="brand"
       ng-model="selectedModel.title"
       ng-init="selectedModel.title=''">
</input>
```

Comment: I had to use this for filling in some default values for a jquery timer, this worked for me:

  if (angular.isUndefined($scope.currentTime)) 
  {
   $scope.currentTime = {begin: $scope.startDate, end:$scope.endDate};
  }

Comment: is ng-init only for use with the $index property of on ng-repeat?

Comment: What I have to put in 'MyService' file if I use    
`MyService.getModel().then(function (model) {
    $scope.selectedModel = model;
    // selected model doesn't have a title set, so give it a blank string as default
    if (angular.isUndefined($scope.selectedModel)) {
      $scope.selectedModel.title = '';
    }
  });`  in controller?